# What is the best model to calculate the free energies using ASE thermochemistry?

Tags: vasp, quantum-espresso, atomic-simulation-environment, thermodynamics, free-energy

I am trying to calculate the free energy of adsorption of a small molecule on a 2D material. After adsorption, I am using the thermochemistry module of the Atomic Simulation Environment to calculate the free energy of the structures. I'm following the example shown [here](https://ritumsc.github.io/Ase_vib/), where the Harmonic approximation has been used.

However, this approximation returns the Helmholtz Free energy. From the documentation of [ASE thermochemistry module](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/thermochemistry/thermochemistry.html)

> This class returns the Helmholtz free energy; if the user assumes the pV term (in H = U + pV) is zero this can also be interpreted as the Gibbs free energy.

**Is the free energy obtained from this approximation useful for plotting free energy diagrams for reactions?**

Any input provided would be highly appreciated.

Comment: despite that Harmonic approximation may not capture all the complexities of the system you are trying to describe, it is still very valuable approximation. I think if you compare the free energy values of different adsorption structures or reaction intermediates, you can gain some understanding of the thermodynamics and energetics of the system, then you can use that to construct free energy diagrams, which could illustrate the energy barriers and overall energy changes during the course of a reaction.